# Proving linearity of $df_x(h)$ when $f$ is subadditive and positive homogenous, but not necessarily differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is a function satisfying $f(x+y)\le f(x)+f(y)$ and $f(tx)=tf(x)$ for all $t\ge 0$, all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$.
Fix an $x$.
Suppose $df_x(h):=\displaystyle\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(x+th)-f(x)}{t}$ exists for all $h\in\mathbb{R}^n$.
Show that $df_x(h_1+h_2)=df_x(h_1)+df_x(h_2)$ for all $h_1,h_2\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

I manage to show that $df_x(ah)=a\cdot df_x(h)$ for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$,
but it's hard to continue from there.
I'm told to examine $L(h):=\displaystyle\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(x+th)-f(x-th)-2f(x)}{t}$,
but I didn't get anything except that $L(h)=0$ iff $df_x(h)$ exists.
Is there any way I can proceed?